# Use same style for TextBlock and Run element

Tags: .net, wpf, styles

I have a WPF style that sets `TextDecorations` dependency property for `TargetType: TexBlock`. I need to use the same style for certain Run elements which are in some TextBlock which doesn't itself use the aforementioned style. How can I achieve this without repeating the same style with just a different `TargetType`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do not specify a `TargetType` but qualify the property, e.g.:

```
<Style x:Key="CommonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Inline.TextDecorations" Value="StrikeThrough" />
</Style>
```

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CommonStyle}" Text="Lorem Ipsum" />
<TextBlock>
    <Run Style="{StaticResource CommonStyle}" Text="Lorem" />
    <Run Text="Ipsum" />
</TextBlock>
```

If you want to further develop the style you can use [`BasedOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx), this also allows implicit application of said style by not setting a key on the derived style.

Comment: Wow. I tried that very same thing, but I set `Property="TextDecorations"` instead of `Property="Inline.TextDecorations"`, and got error "FrameworkElement does not contain...". Adding "Inline." does indeed work.

Comment: I'm interested in the underlying mechanism which enables this, could you please shed some light or some links?

Comment: @H.B. - is there a way to detect this without reflecting the code? Is it stated in the MSDN somewhere that `TextBlock.TextDecorations` 'kidnaps' the `Inline.TextDecorations`?

Comment: @BorisB.: 1. If you use no prefix it will look for the property on `FrameworkElement` because that class owns the `Style` property. 2. `Run` inherits the property from `Inline` and `TextBlock` reuses the property using [`AddOwner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DependencyProperty.AddOwner.aspx). If you see two identical properties on unrelated types it is always worth checking whether one is using the other's property. Decompilers (like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx)) are handy for that. Check the static constructors of classes for the property inits.

Comment: @Erno: I do not think so, i always use a decomplier for that, looked on MSDN but they sadly do not share that information.

Comment: @H.B. - Thanks, at least my MSDN reading skills haven't diminished. Now I will brush up my reflection capabilities ;)